# C++| OOP | How to declare the variable "a" in class inheritance in main function with switch case

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, visual-c++

I am making an exercise to choose and entry a kind of quadrangle with class inheritance then check it's methods. However, my main function runs into errors (Error C2065 'a': undeclared identifier. Error C2371 'a': redefinition; different basic types. E0020 identifier "a" is undefined). Please help me correct

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Quadrangle.h"
#include "Trapezoid.h"
#include "Parallelogram.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        cout << "\n----------MENU----------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Trapezoid" << endl;
        cout << "2. Parallelogram" << endl;
        cout << "3. Rectangle" << endl;
        cout << "4. Square" << endl;
        cout << "----------" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            Trapezoid a;
            break;
        case 2:
            Parallelogram a;
            break;
        case 3:
            Rectangle a;
            break;
        case 4:
            Square a;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please entry again" << endl;
        }

    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);

    a.Set();
    a.CheckCondition();

    cout << "Perimeter = " << a.Perimeter() << endl;
    cout << "Area = " << a.Area() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me declare variable "a" to avoid errors.

Comment: There is no way to declare a variable in automatic storage to have different types depending on some condition at runtime. You'll need to use some form of indirection, like making `a` a `std::unique_ptr` to some common parent class.

Comment: Can you type the sample code for my case?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable `a` inside of the switch statement, so it won't be known outside of this statement(The variable is local to the switch statement). In order to be able to use the variable after the statement you would have to declare it before entering the switch statement and even the while loop.

In order for overriding to work, `a` must be allocated dynamically using `new` and later `delete` because even if you asign a `Trapezoid()` to `a`, `a` would still be a Quadrangle!

```
Quadrangle* a;
do {
    ...
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
         a = new Trapezoid();
    ...
    }

} while...

//A now accessible
cout << "Perimeter = " << a.Perimeter() << endl;

delete a;
```